# Inheritance and Monohehaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

The initial issue is Unity is yelling at me with :

> You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.

I checked the lines this was directed to and only got more confused.

In a MonoBehaviour class I am calling a non-inheriting from anything class with 'new' keyword and attempted use its function in the MonoBehaviour class. ie :

```
public void MonoMethod()
{
     MyNonMonoScript scriptName = new MyNonMonoScript();

     scriptName.NonMonoFunction();
}
```

Can someone elaborate this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
I was creating MonoBehaviour with 'new' keyword and it was in that MyNonMonoScript's other functions that were doing the mono creation with 'new' keyword...
...Oops...